# Number of multisets of length 3 from 8 = 120 not 85 right? (multiset = elements can occur >once but order doesn't matter)

Tags: combinatorics

Question is "decide whether the following are true or false" and one is "the number of multisets of length 3 from 8 elements is 85"

I think false, choosing 3 elements from 8 things where order doesn't matter can be thought of as a sequence of 3 #s and 7-s, for example "#-#--#----" means "1a, 1b, 0d, 1e, 0f 0g 0h 0i" so the number of ways of arranging these 10 things is the number of multisets.

10! ways to arrange them, of those some 7! will actually be the same thing and a further 3! will be the same thing (as the -s and #s cannot be distinguished, so there are 7! ways the -s could show up)

Thus $$\frac{10!}{7!3!}=120$$ not 85.

Am I right?

Comment: If the question is just to decide whether it is $85$, the answer is "no" without much thought. This kind of problem leads to _some_ binomial coefficient, and it is very hard to concoct a factor $17$ from the numbers $3,8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same result: 120

Edit: The formula, which I used, is the formula for combinations with repition: $ n+k-1 \choose k $

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the correct answer is $\frac{8\times9\times10}{1\times2\times3}=120$.